# Calling second method

Tags: c#

Hello I need to Create a method with the parameter radius r. The method calculates and returns the surface of the sphere. The value of the radius r will be a random number from 1 to 20.
Create a method with movie title parameters. The method returns nothing. The method prints the name of the movie in color in all capital letters. The name of the movie is entered by the user.
Call the methods in the main program.
I code this but idk what to do with the second metod and how to call it in main. can you guys help me please

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
        }
        static double PovrchKoule ()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            double nahodnypolomer = rnd.Next(1, 20);
            double vypocet = 4 * Math.PI * nahodnypolomer * nahodnypolomer;

            Console.Write("Nahodný poloměr je: ");
            Console.WriteLine(nahodnypolomer);
            Console.Write("Povrch koule je: ");
            Console.WriteLine(vypocet);
 
        }
        static void Film(string a)
        {
            string film;
            var prevColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.WriteLine("Zadej oblibený film :");
            a = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(film);
            Console.ForegroundColor = prevColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How a sphere relates to a movie?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston: "on principle" is not a valid reason to upvote a question. You [**must only** upvote questions that you believe actually _are_ clear, useful, and well-researched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-it-wrong-to-use-an-upvote-to-balance-out-a-downvote). Voting to offset other votes is specifically against site rules. (As for your complaint that someone downvoted without comment, that _is_ perfectly acceptable and is in no need of any sort of counter-balancing action on your part.)

Comment: @CaseyCrookston answerer with a name resembling yours still think that the question in unclear (they probably also should have downvoted the post for that exact reason) - please continue editing the question so that confusion is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to achieve the following:

1. Calculate the surface area of a sphere with random radius
2. Ask the user about a film name
3. Write this film name in capital letters and in color

The following code should do it:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Generate a random number between 1 and 20
    var random = new Random();
    var radius = radom.Next(1, 20);

    // Call method "AreaOfSphere" with that random number to get the calculated area
    var area = AreaOfSphere(radius);

    // Print the results to the console
    Console.WriteLine("The area of a sphere with radius {0} is {1}", radius, area);


    // After that, ask user about a film title
    Console.Write("Please enter a film title: ");
    var film = Console.ReadLine();

    // Call method "PrintFilmTitle" with the entered title
    // This method will then print the title in color and with capital letters
    PrintFilmTitle(film);
}

private static double AreaOfSphere(double radius)
{
    return Math.PI * radius * radius * 4;
}

private static void PrintFilmTitle(string title)
{
    // Save the current foreground color
    var savedColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

    // Output the title in capital letters and in color
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(film.ToUpper());

    // Reset foreground color to previous color
    Console.ForegroundColor = savedColor;
}
```

The `Console.WriteLine("... {0} ...", radius, ...)` is described here: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___)

Comment: for the first method - the radius should be a parameter, so the random generation should be in the main, and SphereCalculation should receive the value.

private static void SphereCalculation(int radius)
{
...
}

Comment: @audzzy: So the method is just for calculating the area? Something like this?

```cs
private static double AreaOfSphere(double radius)
{
    return radius * radius * 4 * Math.PI;
}

```
This should do the trick.

Comment: "Create a method with the parameter radius r. The method calculates and returns the surface of the sphere. " -  So that's what i understand from that :)

Comment: Oh. I've must have missed that. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: the same goes for the movie - the title should be a parameter.
also - i noticed you're printing the result text in parts..
you could do :

            Console.WriteLine($"The area of a sphere with radius {radius} is {area}");

it would be more readable :)

Comment: I updated my answer again but did not use string interpolation as this is quite hard for beginners. I used the method overload of `Console.WriteLine` which allows string formats.
It is up to debate which representation is more readable / understandable.

Comment: agreed, either way is better than 4 calls to console.write :)